# Generating an image of a section of a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

A simple question, is there anyway to generate an image of a HTML page using javascript or other and save it into, for instance, a data:png/base64 url?

Would it save what the user sees on their screen, or would it try to render the elements? Would it work with z-index positioning and many canvas elements?

And please, no jQuery, etc. I prefer to use the http://vanilla-js.com/ library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Ah, I meant like the user simply having to click a button and the page would be rendered - this seems to be something that someone has to run from the command line (or am I misinterpreting it)?